# Function local ownership where references are required

Tags: elasticsearch, rust, ownership

I am currently trying to build a request to ElasticSearch using the `elasticsearch` dependency.

Below, find the simplified version of the code I have written:

```rust
fn test<'a>(client: &'a Elasticsearch) -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<Bytes, elasticsearch::Error>> {
    let index_parts = ["foo", "bar"]; // Imagine this list being computed and not literal

    let search_response = client
            .search(SearchParts::Index(&index_parts))
            .from(0)
            .size(1000)
            .body(json!(
                { "query": { "match_all": { } } }
            ))
            .send();

    search_response
        .and_then(|resp| resp.bytes())
        .boxed()
}
```

The error I get:

> cannot return value referencing local variable `index_parts`
> returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

I totally understand why I get this error - I create a new array inside of `test`, but `SearchParts::Index` expects only a `&'b [&'b str]`, so I have no way of *giving* ownership to it. So I am stuck with it.

Of course there are a couple of simple solutions to this, first and foremost simply inlining `test` instead of creating a separate function, or somehow returning `index_parts` with the `Future`, but those solutions leak implementation details and we all know that this is bad.

So, how do I fix this error without breaking encapsulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine suggested the following solution:

```
async fn test<'a>(client: &'a Elasticsearch) -> std::result::Result<Bytes, elasticsearch::Error> {
    let index_parts = vec!["foo", "bar"]; // Imagine this list being computed and not literal

    let search_response = client
        .search(SearchParts::Index(&index_parts))
        .from(0)
        .size(1000)
        .body(json!(
            { "query": { "match_all": { } } }
        ))
        .send()
        .await?;

    search_response.bytes().await
}
```

Although I understand that with `async`, everything inside of the function body is effectively a closure, I feel like there should be a way of doing this without using `async` as well, but I am not sure.

There is a further problem with this solution though - the returned `Future` has a lifetime bound to the lifetime of the `Elasticsearch` reference which leads to issues down the line.

To fix this:

```
async fn test(client: & Elasticsearch) -> std::result::Result<Bytes, elasticsearch::Error> {
        let client = client.clone();
        async move {
                let index_parts = ["foo", "bar"];

                let search_response = client
                                .search(SearchParts::Index(&index_parts))
                                .from(0)
                                .size(1000)
                                .body(json!(
                                                { "query": { "match_all": { } } }
                                ))
                                .send()
                                .await?;

                Ok(search_response.bytes().await?)
        }.await
}
```